# Getting out parameter from stored procedure to shell script

Tags: shell, stored-procedures, sap-ase

I have a shell script which executes a stored procedure in the Sybase database. How should I get the out parameter from the procedure?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the whole script or a snippet that contains the database call. You're likely using a client program, and that program might be able to act on the out-parameter. Secondly, if you have control of the stored procedure, you could modify it to `select` the data instead (as a result set), possibly to be printed within your script output for further text processing.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I got it resolved. Did it by just redirecting the output console from stored procedure to a file.

Comment: No problem. Explicitly describing the resolution (eg [answering your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)) might help future knowledge-seekers, if you think you can provide useful information.